# Xamarin i have problem with searhbar and listview

Tags: xamarin

i want to searhbar show the name of my product that i add. i've been watch many tutorial. but i still dont understand it. Please help  me fix this.

this is my xaml code

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            </Grid>
            <SearchBar TextChanged="SearchBar_TextChanged" x:Name="Searbar"></SearchBar>
        
        <ListView x:Name="listview"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="xamarinremovebg.png" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"/>
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                                <Label Text="{Binding NameProduct}"
                                        HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="20"/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Detail}"
                                       HeightRequest="40" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

this is xaml.cs

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        // type on run-time

        listview.ItemsSource = await App.Database2.GetNotesAsync2();


    }
     async private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        listview.BeginRefresh();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.NewTextValue))
            listview.ItemsSource = await App.Database2.GetNotesAsync2();
        else
            listview.ItemsSource = await App.Database2.GetNotesAsync3(Searhbar.Text).

        listview.EndRefresh();
        
        

        
    }
```

and this is model that is  i use

```
public class Product
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NameProduct { get; set; }
    public string image { get ; set; }
        
    public string Detail { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string NameUser { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    
}
```

this is ProductData.cs

```
public Task<Product> GetNoteAsync3(string nexttext)
    {
        return _database2.Table<Product>()
            .Where(i => i.NameProduct.Contains(nexttext));
           
    }
```

this is the error

> 1.'ProductData' does not contain a definition for 'GetNotesAsync3' and no accessible extension method 'GetNotesAsync3' accepting a first
> argument of type 'ProductData' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> 2.Cannot implicitly convert type 'SQLite.AsyncTableQuery<Project.Models.Product>' to
> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Project.Models.Product>'

Comment: you are misspelling **GetNotesAsync3** in `ProductData`

Comment: oh that is my bad but there is still an error like this

Comment: does this only happen on GetNotesAsync3?  Have you compared it to GetNotesAsync2?

Comment: there is still an error like this 1.Cannot implicitly convert type 'SQLite.AsyncTableQuery<Project.Models.Product>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Project.Models.Product>'

Comment: GetNotesAsync2 has no problem it's work

Comment: then I suggest you compare the 2 different methods to determine why one works and one doesn't.  Of if you can't figure it out, post the code for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this method works

```
public Task<List<Product>> GetNotesAsync2()
{
    return _database2.Table<Product>().ToListAsync();
}
```

this one does not

```
public Task<Product> GetNotesAsync3(string nexttext)
{
    return _database2.Table<Product>()
        .Where(i => i.NameProduct.Contains(nexttext));
       
}
```

what's the difference?  The working one returns a `Task<List<Product>>` which makes sense because a query can return multiple rows.  The broken one returns a `Task<Product>` which does not make sense because again, a query can return multiple rows

the working one also uses `ToListAsync()`.  Try modifying the broken method

```
public Task<List<Product>> GetNotesAsync3(string nexttext)
{
    return _database2.Table<Product>()
        .Where(i => i.NameProduct.Contains(nexttext)).ToListAsync();
       
}
```